# Localhost works, but ip gives timout

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, phpmyadmin, lamp

I am trying to setup a LAMP environment on my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.
I have no experience real previous experience with this and all tutorials i find are just a step for step guide on how to setup, but none explain what you are exactly doing. 
So I don't know why I am having this problem.

After installing all parts of LAMP I can access localhost, and I see the apache default page.
But if I try to go to my IPaddress, (the ipaddress I found with curl -4 icanhazip.com) the page loads for a while and then tells me this:

```
    Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 213.127.26.xxx
```

So my question is am I using the right IPaddress and how can I make apache work from my IPaddress? Because phpmyadmin will not work on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that your local ports (i imagine your web server is running on port 80 or 8080) are not being forwarded through your router. Your router likely uses something called “NAT (network address translation)” to expose all of the internal IP addresses on your network through a single “public” IP address, in your case 213.x.x.x (you should never post this here unless you’re 100% positive your network is secure!). Your router needs to be configured to forward port 80 on 213.x.x.x to your machine’s “internal” ip address, likely something like “192.168.x.x” or “10.0.x.x”. A search for “port forwarding ” should help you out

Alternatively, `ngrok` is a nice free tool which you can use to expose your port on a public address. By running `nginx http 80`, it will provide you with a temporary url where you can reach your site (on a free plan, it will only provide you that url for one day, so you will need to re-run it)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find out on which ports your server is running.

After that, you have to go into your router's settings and add port forwarding entries for these ports, to make sure that your router forwards the requests to the right device.